# CSS Menu Bar Hiding Behind Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried all the solutions that I can find on Google, but somehow, all information about the z-index don't really work :(. It's my first time using this site, so forgive me if my content seems messy.

**Problem 1**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jr5wew27ydv7hcl/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-16%20at%2011.57.01%20pm.png

**Problem 2**:https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ffztfq7iezc4ao/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-16%20at%2011.57.50%20pm.png

**My Own CSS Sheet**

```
    .header{
    width:960px;
    height:99px;
    font-family:'Francois One', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    z-index:9999px;}
    <!--this holds the css menu bar-->

    .banner, #slidermain {
    width:960px;
    height:328px;}
    <!--this holds the nivo slider-->

    .slidermain {
    background-color:#399;
    margin-bottom:10px;}
```

**Nivo Slider CSS Sheet**

```
/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
    z-index:10px;

}

.nivoSlider img {
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    max-width: none;
}
.nivo-main-image {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

If the css menu position is set to relative, it would work, but the dropdowns will push the nivo slider downwards to fit its size, causing other tables to shift downwards too. But once the mouse is away from the menu bar, the nivo slider resizes to its original position.

```
/* user menu settings */
.ddmenu { 
  display: block;
  padding:5px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:45px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #656565;
  font-weight: normal;
  float: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s linear;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
}
.ddmenu:hover { color: #898989; }

.ddmenu.open {
  background: #5a90e0;
  color: #fff;
  border-left-color: #6c6d70;
  position:relative;
  z-index:200px;
}

.ddmenu ul { 
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px; /* move content -1px because of container left border */
  width: 200px;
  z-index:200px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  border-left: 4px solid #8e9196;
  background: #fff;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Any help rendered would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: This is not right, `z-index:200px;`, you don't assign a pixel size to it just `200`. Also, not 100% sure, if the css is on it's own stylesheet you should not use html comments like so, `<!--this holds the nivo slider-->`, if it is, instead use `/* Comment goes here */`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use a position relative for menu first level and add position absolute for a menu 2 level so: 'home, services, event, information, about us, contact' must have position relative, for another ul where is: 'about sana, partners' set position absolute and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You added a unit to your z-indexes, but the z-index property is not allowed to have a unit: 
[W3C: z-index](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

Try removing the "px" from all your z-indexes, that should solve your problem.

Comment: it doesn't work..when i removed the px in all z-indexes problem two still persists (menu bar pushes nivo slider downwards)